# IOS App - Login With Laravel - API - Passport Or sanctum

Tags: ios, laravel, api, authentication

Our team is building IOS app with laravel as backend.
They need to implement plain login from IOS with mail / pwd along with other social logins i.e Google/Apple. Which approach should I use.I am quiet lost here, any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: If you don't require [OAuth](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/which-oauth-2-0-flow-should-i-use) then use [Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum) in conjunction with [Socialite](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/socialite). If you do require OAuth, then use [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passpor) or alternatively consider a 3rd party auth provider such as [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) which will manage all that stuff for you (at a cost).

Comment: If we go with Sanctum & Socialite we would be still able to login With Google & Apple from the IOS device? Thnx for the prompt response.

Comment: There are packages for assisting with [iOS/socialite integration](https://laravel-news.com/sign-in-with-apple-for-laravel).